# Constant in mylib.h not useable

Tags: c, integer, constants

I'm just starting out teaching myself C
I've learned that it is usual to create constants in mylib.h using #define CONSTANT = value

However when I try to use that value I get a complete failure. Below I added the code of my mylib.h

```
#define MYLIB_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define N_PEOPLE = 10

typedef struct
{
  int status;
  int days;
} Person;

typedef struct
{
  Person p[N_PEOPLE];
  int sick;
  int healthy;
  int dead;
  int imune;
} Model;


int solve

  ( int test);
```

In this instance the code doesn't work.
when I replace the line `Person  p[N_PEOPLE];` by `Person p[10];` It does work.

Comment: That's because your macro makes it `Person p[= 10];`

Comment: Where on earth did you learn that?

Comment: Additionally, you are missing some critical bits of your import guards. It should be ```#ifndef MYLIB_H #define MYLIB_H ... #endif```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When expanded, `Person p[N_PEOPLE];` will become `Person p[= 10];`.  This is a syntax error.

Remove the `=` from the definition:

```
#define N_PEOPLE 10
```